Would test set MSE and r^2 be the same with OLS and PC Regression with all PCs?
For this question, I define:
PC Regression = Standardize Variables, Fit PCA, then apply OLS to all PCs.
OLS = Standardize Variables, then apply OLS with all variables.
This question makes me think the answer is "yes" since PCA with all PCs is just a set of linear combinations on the original data. So, even on the test set, there is no loss of information and OLS should be able to have same out of sample R2/MSE since it is also linear.
However, I did some toy examples and did not see the exact same test set r2... maybe some data was being dropped or there is some numeric or floating point issue at play.
Now that I think of it... I think that standardizing may be introducing some noise. When I don't standardize the data and run OLS and PC regression I get much closer results.
pcr = Pipeline([("ss", StandardScaler()), ("pc", PCA()), ("model", LinearRegression())])
pcr.fit(X_train, y_train)
pcr.score(X_test, y_test)
0.5708763714065296

pcr = Pipeline([("ss", StandardScaler()), ("model", LinearRegression())])
pcr.fit(X_train, y_train)
pcr.score(X_test, y_test)
0.5708405442855263

pcr = Pipeline([("model", LinearRegression())])
pcr.fit(X_train, y_train)
pcr.score(X_test, y_test)
0.570828508037032

pcr = Pipeline([ ("pc", PCA()), ("model", LinearRegression())])
pcr.fit(X_train, y_train)
pcr.score(X_test, y_test)
0.5708285080369971





I linked that in the question..would like some clarifications

A difference that small is going to be roundoff error from floating point calculations, especially when we know, mathematically speaking, that the results with infinite-precision arithmetic would be the same.

so it is because these are linearly the same... but 0.57087 and 0.57084 are pretty different. Could standard scaler cause some issues here?

The more calculations you do, the more roundoff error due to finite precision you'll have.

... and, from a practical perspective, there is no difference between an $R^2$ of 0.57087 and 0.57084.

Whether 0.57087 and 0.57804 can be considered different numbers depends on the details: how much data you have; their typical values and ranges; and even the specific algorithms that are used for PCA etc.  Because you offer none of that information, all we can provide is general speculative comments rather than answers.
